# Is $f: [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous if it is uniformly continuous on every compactum $[0,R]$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider a function $f: [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is uniformly
>   continuous on $[0,R]$, where $0 \leq R < 1$. Does this also mean that
>   $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1)$?

I think that $f$ has to be continuous on $[0,1)$ but not necessarily uniformly continuous. To prove just continuity, I would do a proof by contradiction: if $f$ is not continuous on $[0,1)$, we find a point $r_0 \in [0,1)$ where $f$ is not continuous, but then we find $ 0\leq r_0< R< 1$ such that $f$ is uniformly continuous there, hence continuous. But I do not see yet a counter example for $f$ not being uniformly continuous on $[0,1)$, but I think it should not be true.

Comment: Your misconception is thinking that if a function is not uniformly continuous on an interval then it must be discontinuous at some point.  It's the uniformity that is violated, not the continuity.

Comment: @ErickWong Sorry, clarified the question. I think that $f$ is just continuous but not necessarily uniformly continuous on $[0,1)$. This is true?

Comment: **Locally**, continuity implies uniform continuity because $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < h$ for $|x-x_0| < a$ means that $|f(x)-f(y)| < 2h$ for $|x-y| < a/2, |x-x_0| < a/2$. But this works only for compacts, i.e. the sets that are covered by finitely many such balls $|x-x_0| < a$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, let $f(x)=1/(1-x)$ is uniformly continue on every compact interval $[0,R]$ but is not uniformly continuous on $[0,1)$. In general, a continuous function defined on a compact interval is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks. But the continuity is true?

Comment: Yes it is continuous since it is the restriction of a continuous function.